# Adding a vehicle to the vehicle routing example

Tags: optaplanner

Our situation is similar to the vehicle routing example. The difference is we want to be able to add vehicles on the fly. When adding a vehicle through a problemfactchange (with BeforeEntityAdded & AfterEntityAdded) the log verifies that the problem fact change is done, but the planner doesn't seem to take the new vehicle into account. It is done using code below (depot is an existing depot). Any ideas how to fix this?

```
Vehicle vehicle = new Vehicle();
vehicle.setId(id);
vehicle.setCapacity(5);
vehicle.setDepot(depot);
scoreDirector.beforeEntityAdded(vehicle);
solution.getVehicleList().add(vehicle);
scoreDirector.afterEntityAdded(vehicle);
scoreDirector.triggerVariableListeners();
```

Thanks

Comment: You 'll want to shallow clone the vehicleList to avoid former best solution events's bestSolution to change if they're used in another thread (such as the UI thread).

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the next best solution event, after that problem fact change, and it has that vehicle in the list, it should be possible to use. Are you sure that the capacity is high enough and there's a way to use the vehicle to get to a better score?

Try solving a VRP set with less capacity that the required demand, then add a vehicle - it should be used immediately as using it will improve the hard score.